# Using meta.summaries for confidence intervals from epi.2by2

Tags: r, statistics, meta

I'm looking to get an average value based on a range of values each with associated error. I've found that meta.summaries from the `rmeta` package seems to be working pretty well, but the error I have on the input values is only upper and lower bounds, not a standard error measurement, coming from use of `epi.2by2`. `Meta.summaries` needs a standard error.

Is there a way to make `meta.summaries` use upper and lower bounds, or `epi.2by2` to generate a s.e?

```r
attach(DATA)
m <- summary(meta.summaries(RR,SE), conf.level = 0.95)
```

Comment: Hello! You can use ticks like `\`this\`` to highlight code. Also, if you want some answers, you should provide data, so that can people can stop. You can use already accessible datasets such as `iris` or `AirPassengers` or `cars`... or just make up a new data set.

Comment: And if you want non-`rmeta` experts to get interested, you should probably provide some context. For instance, "to get an average value based on a range of values each with associated error" sounds pretty generic to me ;)

Comment: Thanks Arthur. So I've got some estimates for some odds ratios e.g. 1.03, upper = 1.04, lower = 1.02, and since they represent similar things, I want to average them but incorporate their errors so the average I get out at the end has its own error attached

Comment: So you want confidence bounds / risk measurement on a average of odd ratios? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: And I maintain that you should provide data (fake or not) for people to work on your problem. We are all working for free here, and looking for data is tedious. `DATA`, `RR` and `SE` make your exemple not self-contained nor reproducible. As a general rule, if you want answers, you probably want to simplify the task of answering :)

Comment: I'd like a value which represents the standard error on the risk ratio which I can carry forwards to meta.summaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe do you rely too much on packages? From Wikipedia's [Odd-Ratio page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio), I can read:

> The distribution of the log odds ratio is approximately normal with:
>
> L ~ N( log(OR), s^2 )

... where s can be approximated by:

> SE=sqrt(1 / n_11 + 1/n_01 + 1/n_00 + 1/n_10)

(Where n_11 are the number of cured among exposed to a drug, n_10 the number of cured among non exposed, etc.) You can thus compute very easily your standard errors. Suppose that you pack all your observation as a data set:

```r
n      <- 10                                       # number of odd-ratios
counts <- sample(20:100, replace = TRUE, size=4*n) # fake counts data
counts <- matrix(counts, cols=4)                   # one line = one experiment = one OR = 4
```

... you can then compute your standard errors as the following:

```r
se <- sqrt(rowSums(1/counts))
```

Please note that:

> This is an asymptotic approximation, and will not give a meaningful result if any of the cell counts are very small.

... and more generally that **averaging odd-ratios sounds dubious**, too me at least. If you have the original observations, then you can simply put all the counts together. If you don't, then you're going to overweight small studies in the process. I did not investigate in detail but there seems to be much discussion over the matter: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5352535/. You can also see what is said [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9483/how-to-calculate-confidence-intervals-for-pooled-odd-ratios-in-meta-analysis) on CrossValidated (the StackOverFlow for statistics).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Arthur. Since I have the underlying data, putting all the counts together sounds like a much more robust idea, and will inevitably simplify the code I have to write to get the output type I'm looking for.